# Use Jenkins API to find information about the current user

Tags: api, jenkins

I'm building a client-side dashboard that makes use of the Jenkins REST API to fetch data about jobs. That's the easy part. I haven't yet figured out how to display, for example, the current user's name (though I did find the path to any particular user, but that's not dynamic: `[jenkinsRoot]/users/[name]/api` ).

Is there a hidden REST path that contains any information about the current user?

If not, is there an alternative? I've already checked the cookie, and it doesn't have the username.

Comment: What user would you expect to get info for?  The user making the rest request with an API token?

Comment: No api token. These users would simply log in via the standard Jenkins login page. Then, when they visit the page with the dashboard, their authentication cookies just ride along with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I can find to hit data about a user in Jenkins 1.5 is:

```
  /user/[user_name]/api/[json|xml]
```

Currently, there doesn't seem to be a REST endpoint for 'who am i'.  Also, none of the other resources look as if they expose the current user.

I guessing it's assumed if you're using the credentials with the [user_name] to authenticate you should just enter it in the request ULR for the user resource endpoint to get the user resource.

You could probably make a simple plugin to expose the currently authenticated user: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exposing+data+to+the+remote+API

Comment: As I expected. Oh well. Thanks for also giving me a potential solution via a custom plugin. I've skimmed and it seems quite doable. Now, to convince management/systems to let me implement it... that's the challenge.

Comment: @jonas.ninja  If you do you should contribute it or make it available on github--others might find it useful too

Comment: Most definitely. I'll come back to this question and put a link if it happens.

Answer (score 1):

As of at least v1.565.3, you can get some good info at `/me/api/json`.